# Why was a hive mapreduce job killed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hue

I executed a hive sql on hue. but the related mapreduce job was killed.

How to find the reason?
Where to find the related logs?

Can not find the log through the job history.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your log generation is set to INFO, so you can find your logs on your jobtracker node in the directory you setted.
If you do not know what directory it is, you can search using following command :
`find / -name userlogs` then you should be able to find the file corresponding to your job ID.

To sum up the logs are written locally so you can find them until you suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

The Hive logs should appear on the screen and the list of MapReduce jobs on the left.

Clicking on the Job ids will send you to Job Browser where you can see the logs of the tasks in deep details.