# How to find the reason for hive mapreduce job that killed automatically

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I have executed hive query and it got killed automatically (not manually by anyone)

I am not able to find the reason in any of the logs.

Cloudera version : 5.4.11
Hive : 1.1.0

I see the similar question in following link but no luck

[Why was a hive mapreduce job killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628758/why-was-a-hive-mapreduce-job-killed)

Answer (score 0):

Check you job history here: `http://<YARN-JobHistory-Server>:19888/jobhistory​`

Comment: Thanks Ani , I checked the job history couldn't find any reason in logs attempt_1490572565328_1051_m_000000_0 KILLED  /default/xxx:8042 logs Mon Mar 27 10:56:15 -0400 2017 Mon Mar 27 10:56:18 -0400 2017 2sec Task KILL is received. Killing attempt!

Comment: Task kill is received means there was a user based kill command passed , which killed the job. it could be ctrl+C too.

Comment: or closing the terminal from which you ssh'd (if not using the screen command)...